# Deduping data before scraping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website for data.  However I have noticed there may be duplication of data when compared to previous days.

I would like to be able to compare and dedup the data before writing them in a dataframe.

Let's say I start today; I would like to use yesterday's data as my baseline and do the comparison and remove any duplication. And tomorrow compared to today and so.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? :-). Please show some effort!

Comment: Can you also provide some example data?

Comment: Apologies been swamped didn't get round to it.
So far not much:

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#op.add_argument('headless')
homepage = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=op)
homepage.get("site")

date_string1 = "06/08/2020"
try:
    page_data= homepage.find_element_by_partial_link_text(date_string1).click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Nonew info found")

I haven't structure the code properly thus far.
The idea is to use date_string to  click on the link and then compare with the previous date (may not be consecutive).

Comment: I was thinking of putting first_date and second date data into sets and then do the dedup.
Data is a bunch of IP addresses.